# Updating Variable in HTML with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, updating

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm building a game. Whenever the player clicks on the gold image, he should get 1 gold. So I have the following HTML piece of code:

```
<li id="gold">Gold: 0</li>
```

That's the starting gold, and through JQuery I update that with:

```
$('#gold-image').click(function() {
    gold++;
    $('#gold').replaceWith('<li id="gold">Gold: ' + gold + '</li>');
});
```

But I don't feel that's the best way to update how much gold the player has. Is there a way that I can write in the HTML to update the variable whenever it's being changed or something like that without having to replace that whole item?

Later in the game there will be many functions running at the same time and increasing the gold number, so I think replacing HTML code is not the optimal way.

Comment: If it matters at all to you whether your players will be able to cheat or not, you won't do this. JavaScript is a **client-side** language, which means the client can simply change the value of gold he has at will. Read into the difference between server-side and client-side languages.

Comment: no, there is no automatic varialbe-interpolation in HTML with JavaScript. But you can simplify your code by adding a `<span id="gold">0</span>` arround the number. Then you can update it with `$('#gold').text(10)`.

Comment: @NickBull For this project I don't really care if people try to cheat or not. But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with your existing div `<div id="gold">Gold: 0</div>`:

```
$('#gold-image').click(function() {
    gold++;
    $('#gold').html('Gold: ' + gold);
});
```

Although the above code would work. I would NOT use jQuery for something like this. There are other frameworks which would be way better for such applications. For example you can take a look at AngularJS or Ember.

The same functionality can be achieved using the two-way binding with [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).

1) the markup:

```
<div controller="GameCtrl">
  <img src="/path/to/img.png" ng-click="goldClicked()">
  <div>Gold {{ gold }}</div>  
</div>
```

2) the javascript code

```
app.controller('GameCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.gold = 0;
  $scope.goldClicked = function() {
    $scope.gold += 1;
  };
});
```

The code is very very simple and you do not need to deal with selectors. Every time you change the **gold** (or any other variable) it will automatically be updated in the DOM. You will automatically get modular code and dependency injection. In addition you will write everything declaratively and your code will be much easier to read and easy to change in future.

**UPDATE:** Here is a working AngularJS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/absolutemystery/7WgYK/

Comment: I will definitely try these frameworks. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Or, using a div only around the number (e.g., `<div id="gold">0</div>`),

```
$('#gold-image').click(function() {
    $('#gold').html(++gold);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could user [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) for this kind of thing. Ember.js its a MVC javascript library.

In this case:

```
<li id="gold">Gold: {{YourController.goldAmmount}}</li>
```

and them in your controler you only have to call the function updateAmmount():

```
var YourController= Em.ArrayController.create({
   goldAmmount : 0,

   updateAmmount : function(){
      this.goldAmmount++;
   }

})
```

Comment: Seems great! I don't know about Ember.js, but I will about it and try to use it. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah it's, Follow the tutorial in their web site and then try to build whatever you want. I've been using Ember.js in a large web application.

Comment: Knockout has similar bindings as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a `<span>` element it would make it a little cleaner:

HTML:

```
<li>Gold: <span id="gold">0</span></li>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#gold-image').click(function() {
    gold++;
    $('#gold').text(gold);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom events for that. Everytime gold value updates, you can trigger an event, passing an argument, for example:

```
$('#gold-image').click(function() {
    gold++;
    jQuery.event.trigger({type: "onGoldUpdate",val:gold});
});
```

After that, you can be always listening to that event and do whatever you want with this information, like this:

```
jQuery(document).on("onGoldUpdate", function(e){  
    var goldValue = e.val;
    jQuery('.gold .value').html(goldValue);
});
```

And on HTML part, you can put a span around the value:

```
<li id="gold">Gold: <span class="value">0</span></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple MVVM solution for your needs, for example Knockout.js. You can create a model and bind it's values to a place in your html and anytime you update a value in the model the rendered html is automatically updated without your interference. Quick example of how you could use it here...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script>
function PlayerModel() {

    // the player score
    this.playerGold = ko.observable(0);

    // The increase gold function to add 1 to the player score
    this.increaseGold = function() {
        var oldScore = parseInt(this.playerGold());
        this.playerGold(++oldScore);
    };
}

var model = new PlayerModel();

$( document ).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(model);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>Gold : <strong data-bind="text: playerGold"></strong></li>
<button onclick="javascript:model.increaseGold()">Standard JS - Increase gold</button>
<button data-bind="click: increaseGold">KO Data bound -Increase gold</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Its as easy as that. You can add more variables easily to your player model then if you want. I like this approach because it keeps things easy but also affords you a lot of control over the implementation etc. Ember is another great alternative though.